# Why isn't there a do while flow control statement in python?

Tags: python

Is there a good reason why there isn't a do while flow control statement in python?

Why do people have to write `while` and `break` explicitly?

Comment: "write while ... explicitly"?  What does this mean?  How does `do while` not write `while` explicitly?  I don't get this part of the question.

Comment: What is the reason for needing to know this?  How does this factoid help you solve any programming problems?

Comment: It's a very good question, and a common source of distress for new Python users.

Comment: @S.Lott: It doesn't. But it does help me to understand the Pythonic way of doing things. When learning new languages you wonder about features that are missing or new features that don't exist in one language.

Comment: This is a very good question and I would like to know too why there isn't a `do while` loop in python.

Comment: @renatov Read the answer's link to PEP 315

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has been proposed in [PEP 315](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) but hasn't been implemented because nobody has come up with a syntax that's clearer than the `while True` with an inner `if-break`.

Comment: Have a look at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-February/060718.html which is linked from the PEP.  It explains the problem with various syntax alternatives in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 10):

Probably because Guido didn't think it was necessary. There are a bunch of different flow-control statements you could support, but most of them are variants of each other. Frankly, I've found the do-while statement to be one of the less useful ones.

Comment: +1,  i almost always want my conditions at the top.  makes the 'zero case' a lot cleaner.

Comment: Yes, probably GuiDO didn't think it worthWHILE

Comment: in Pascal I always use repeat-until(condition). In C++ I use do-while(condition) rarely. Can you explain that? :)

Comment: `while` itself is pretty useless when you have generators. Haven't used it in years for anything other than `while True`.

Comment: @Nick:  I used repeat-until a lot when I did Pascal also.  However, that was in the early-mid 1980's when I was in college.  Usually  the programs were text-based, menu-driven, and interactive, so the menu always had to appear at least once.  A repeat-until made sense then.  Now, most of my programming is file driven, so a while makes more sense.

Comment: I learned from EWD's *A Discipline of Programming*, so I can only use `while` and have only used `while` (and `for`).  I saw other loop constructs, but couldn't figure out why there had to be so many syntax alternatives when `while` (and `for`) had the easiest proof rules.

Answer (score 3):

Because then you would have two ways to do something.

Comment: A do-while/repeat-until loop is not the same thing as a while loop.  The former will always execute at least once, but the latter may not execute at all.

Comment: @GreenMatt, that's not what he's talking about. You'll then have 2 ways to manually loop on a condition. Pre and post conditions don't _really_ differ enough to justify extending the Python syntax.

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Firstly, I don't presume to know what Austin was thinking when he made that entry.  To address your comment:  I realize that the thinking is that Python doesn't need the extra looping structure.  I'm just pointing out the difference lest someone who doesn't know otherwise would think the two looping mechanisms do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @GreenMatt, fair enough then. We're all friends here, long live Guido.

Comment: +1 From a language design perspective, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Python adds features only when they significantly simplify some code.

```
while True:
    ...
    if not cond: break
```

is not less simple than a do-while loop, for which there is no obvious natural python syntax anyway.

```
do:
    ...
    while cond
```

(Looks weird)

or this?

```
do:
    ...
while cond
```

(The while looks like a regular while statement)

Comment: `break`s in a conditional in the middle of the loop does require more code parsing than parsing an explicit `do… until…` structure.  So, code reading would be simplified.  As for the `while cond` looking weird, it could be replaced by an equivalent `until cond`, which would be explicit.  I guess that there are good reasons to not have a do… until control structure, however; reading the original discussion  would probably be useful.